# Excel User Defined Function evaluates to zero if another workbook is opened

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I have created a user defined function (UDF) in Excel VBA, which picks up contents from 2 columns and evaluates to a result. The UDF evaluates correctly when no other workbooks are open, but changes to zero when any other workbooks are opened simultaneously. I think the issue is in the first few steps, where I read the input:

```
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(inputSheet)
For i = 0 To numrows
    array_multi(i, 0) = Cells(inputRow1 + i, inputCol1)
    array_multi(i, 1) = Cells(inputRow2 + i, inputCol2)
Next
```

Can someone help me resolve the issue here? Let me know if you require more details.

Comment: Post the _whole_ UDF.

Comment: `Cells()` must be referenced in the sheet where they are supposed to be, or the values will be read in the `Activesheet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you use the *Sheet* which you never use when assigning values to your array.

```
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(inputSheet)
array_multi(i, 0) = Cells(inputRow1 + i, inputCol1)
array_multi(i, 1) = Cells(inputRow2 + i, inputCol2)
```

Try using the *Sht.Cells* to make sure your array reads the values from the right worksheet and workbook.

```
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(inputSheet)
For i = 0 To numrows
    array_multi(i, 0) = Sht.Cells(inputRow1 + i, inputCol1)
    array_multi(i, 1) = Sht.Cells(inputRow2 + i, inputCol2)
Next
```

Comment: I thought `ThisWorkbook` was specifically about not taking different values but always be the workbook the code is in.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct you are right, just need to fix the reference to the `Sht` object

Comment: ah I missed the missing sheet reference in the next lines. So the problem is that `ActiveSheet` which is used by `Cells` is changing.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct feel free to +1 :)

Comment: Your solution is probably the right fix but tbh I'm not convinced by the explanation

Comment: @arcadeprecinct If the `Cells()` declaration is not assigned a specific reference sheet (ie `Sht.Cells()`), it will automatically be assigned to the active sheet which can cause any number of problems.  This issue is most commonly seen when using the Worksheet.Range() command where Range is filled by Cells.  Even though the Range has been assigned to the Worksheet, the subsequent Cells declarations will be assigned to the active sheet, which will throw an error since a Range cannot be defined by cells on another sheet

Comment: @RGA yes I know, my problem was that it originally said that `ThisWorkbook` was changing depending on what's active.

Answer (score 0):

The `Cells` object refers to the `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` unless qualified. You could use

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(inputSheet)
    For i = 0 To numrows
        array_multi(i, 0) = .Cells(inputRow1 + i, inputCol1)
        array_multi(i, 1) = .Cells(inputRow2 + i, inputCol2)
    Next i
End With
```

As Shai's answer is 100% right please accept and upvote his answer.